# Mongoose validation triggers error but data is still stored

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The mongoose documentation claims that if validation fails it will not store the data. However the following code does store invalid data posted to /api/orders. The console.write does print the expected error but the data is already in the database at that point.

> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate "This
>   method is called pre save and if a validation rule is violated, save
>   is aborted and the error is returned to your callback."

code:

```
app.post('/api/orders', function(req, res) {
    var OrderItem = new Order(req.body);
    OrderItem.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.send(OrderItem);
    });
});

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: String, required: true, match: /^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}$/}, //\p{L}
    lines: [{
        name: String,
        count: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5}
    }]
});

var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

invalid data:

```
{ user: '0123456789', lines: [] }
```

Error message:

```
{ message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { user:
      { message: 'Path `user` is invalid (0123456789).',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'user',
        type: 'regexp',
        value: '0123456789' } } }
```

I assume I misunderstand how this is supposed to work but i can't find the error.

Comment: can you try if (err) console.log(err); instead of console.log(err); and share the results?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that doc that fails validation but is being saved?

Comment: How are you concluding that the items is saved? Because using the exact same code I get a validation error for an invalid entry and it's not stored in the database at all.

Comment: I can see the invalid data in my database. I will add the invalid data and the error now.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid data is definitely not stored in the database. Use the following test on your computer to make sure no document is saved by mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sotest');

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: String, required: true, match: /^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}$/}, //\p{L}
    lines: [{
        name: String,
        count: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5}
    }]
});

var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

var OrderItem = new Order({ user: '0123456789', lines: [] });
Order.collection.remove(function(err) {
    OrderItem.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        Order.find({}, function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            assert(docs.length == 0, "No documents should be saved in the db!");
            Order.collection.remove(function(err) {});
        });
    });
});
```

If you can still see the data, it probably means that you didn't clear the content of the collection that the data is in.